# Initialize value converter class in each row in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a doubt. I have `ListView` in my wpf app and I am setting its data context/item source to a datatable from sql server. I am able to populate the `ListView` with data from datatable, But the third column is a combobox in each row. So we can change the values in the comboxbox at any time. But if we change it, how can I check or keep the original selected value for later reference ?

If I change the value in the `ComboBox`, I want to change the color of `ComboBox`. If I revert back to the original value, then give back the normal color to combox.

I created a value converter class and declared a dependency property in it. My plan was to set the original binded value to this dependency property and combo's background color set to this value converter.

After defining the dependency property, I am not able to initialize the value converter class in the XAML.

Is this the correct approach ? is there anything like setting a class instance along with each `ListView` row item ?

Comment: Please post your code of what you've done so far

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MVVM, you should have an `OldValue` and a `SelectedValue` property in your ViewModel, and change combobox color using a trigger that checks if `SelectedValue` is `OldValue`.